# Webfonts not rendering on IE11 win8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, webfonts

I have a weird problem with webfonts rendering on IE11 (v11.0.9600.17631) windows 8.1 pro.

I am using both an iconmoon produced iconset and 2 typekit fonts (proxima nova and rooney) and nothing is rendered using these.

I have tried so many things but nothing seems to do the job. Tried a dozen tweaks on my css, also a number of google webfonts, generated a couple of tests through fontsquirrel. Nothing works.

It doesn't look like i am having CORS issues, on several of these tests fonts are on the same directory as the application i am building.

I managed to get it to work by disabling protected mode in Internet Options > Security, which i understand its turned on by default.

Anybody faces similar issues? This is so disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be in the browsers emulation mode (Compatibility View). Force the UserAgent for IE by including this as the first metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

[x-ua-compatible](/questions/tagged/x-ua-compatible) [ie-compatibility-mode](/questions/tagged/ie-compatibility-mode)

Comment: I believe it had to do with some security settings of windows. I tried a lof of different things so i am not sure what was wrong.

I had the tag already but not first. It didn't seem to make a difference, i mean, i moved it to the top, but it didn't break when i put i back where it was. 
I appreciate your time. Thanks